# Duplicate records being returned in MySQL

Tags: mysql, 4d-database

Unfortunately for most of my career I use a freaky french database called 4th dimension.  And it acted very differently from MySQL.    So please bear with me on what could be avery simple question.

I have bult a query as follows:

```
SELECT c.id, p.last_name, e.full_name, l.Current_step, l.Current_Step_date,  
FROM customer as c, lesson as l , Employee as e 
WHERE l.Prospect_ID =c.id
AND c.ID_ofProducer= e.id  
AND last_name = 'Smith'
```

I am getting back 3 records.  But they are all the same.

```
ID      Last_name     Full_name     Current_Step      Current_Step_date
61245   Smith         Jim Jones     Registered        2013-04-14
61245   Smith         Jim Jones     Registered        2013-04-14
61245   Smith         Jim Jones     Registered        2013-04-14
```

I DID expect to get `61245  Smith` back.

But; I did not expect to get it back echoed 3 times.

Can someone possibly shed some light on what the heck I did wrong/  what I should have done?

Comment: sure it's the db and not your code running and/or display the results 3 time?

Comment: You're selecting 3 tables.

Comment: Try adding DISTINCT or GROUP BY -- one of your records is in one of those 3 tables multiple times causing the duplicate results.

Comment: Yup  both of them solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably differences in other fields.  To see them, this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer as c, lesson as l , Employee as e 
WHERE l.Prospect_ID =c.id
AND c.ID_ofProducer= e.id  
AND last_name = 'Smith'
```

If there are no differences, then there are duplicates in one or more of the tables.

If you want to eliminate such duplicates, you can do so with the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT distinct c.id, p.last_name, e.full_name, l.Current_step, l.Current_Step_date
FROM customer as c, lesson as l , Employee as e 
WHERE l.Prospect_ID =c.id
AND c.ID_ofProducer= e.id  
AND last_name = 'Smith'
```

If that is not supported, you can do the same thing with `group by`:

```
SELECT c.id, p.last_name, e.full_name, l.Current_step, l.Current_Step_date
FROM customer as c, lesson as l , Employee as e 
WHERE l.Prospect_ID =c.id
AND c.ID_ofProducer= e.id  
AND last_name = 'Smith' 
group by c.id, p.last_name, e.full_name, l.Current_step, l.Current_Step_date
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what SQL database does not support `DISTINCT`? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson . . . To quote the OP:  "I use a freaky french database called 4th dimension".  This is also why I'm not mentioning the implicit joins; the database may not support `join` syntax.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a little bit fizzy on what exactly a MYsql query returns.  I am used to having a record set returned to me.  That is to say the database returns me an array of pointers to the appropriate records.  Usually it is a single bit in the directory that indicates  YES  on NO   that it is part of the record set.   (Hey this is old school and saved a ton of memory when 64K was absolute luxury)   It seems that mySql actually makes an extraction of the data you ask for, from the database and presents as a 'copy' in rows.  Am I wacky here?

Comment: @JVMX . . . The return set would generally be a copy of the data.  Such memory limitations are no longer the driving concern of databases.  In a typical engine, the data would be copied as it gets transferred to the user/application.  In fact, a point just wouldn't work, because the memory space of the database would (typically/hopefully) be protected from other applications.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This solidifies what I thought I was seeing mySQL do.  Sigh.  The problem I find with being 'old school' is that I find it hard to simply trust how something will work if don't understand what is going on down underneath.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `GROUP BY` aggregate function.

```
SELECT c.id, p.last_name, e.full_name, l.Current_step, l.Current_Step_date,  
FROM customer as c, lesson as l , Employee as e 
WHERE l.Prospect_ID =c.id
AND c.ID_ofProducer= e.id  
AND last_name = 'Smith'   
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: An incomplete `GROUP BY` will indeed work on MySQL where it'll select a random row, but it will not work on any other database. What will work everywhere is a `DISTINCT`.